# When using github to store an excel file, file seems to revert back to an old version every time

Tags: excel, github

I am trying to store an excel file in github. The file is a master list of "off limits entities" that my team must use and each update daily with items that the full team needs to exclude from their data analyses. Here is our current workflow:

- Pull most recent version of "off_limits_entities.xlsx" list before starting work
- Edit "off_limits_entities.xlsx" locally (generally, will add 10 - 50 entries in various columns and sheets)
- Push "off_limits_entities.xlsx" to github

The problem is that when I do this, and then one of my teammates does the same, when we pull again our files are both missing all recent additions (even though our pushes and pulls all seemed to be successful). As a test, I created a smaller xlsx file (one sheet) and uploaded it to github, then had one of my teammates pull, edit, and push it, and when I pulled the same file, it WAS updated appropriately with new columns and cells. I also considered whether our "off limits entities" files was too large, but it is only 223KB and the github limit is 100MB.

Does anyone know why the github might be **losing/not saving/erasing new entries** in the file?

Comment: Are you committing your changes before your push?

Comment: `.xlsx` is likely a compressed MSXML file, which git will treat as a binary file (which it is), so it won't merge different commits but simply overwrite it with whatever is pushed latest. Use a plain text format (e.g. CSV), or use a proper tool (e.g. Google Docs) to manage Excel files.

Comment: @sean yes committing before pushing, and not having this issue with any non-excel files

Comment: @mustaccio interesting, will try as a csv and see how it goes. I'm still confused about why this method fails with my main project ("off limits entities") but worked just fine with a test file (a single sheet, single column file)

Comment: "worked just fine with a test file" -- because only one person has modified it?